# Run processes concurrently with stdin, stdout

Tags: haskell, stdout, stdin

How can I expand "[Running processes concurrently](https://wiki.haskell.org/Running_processes_concurrently)" to include stdin and stdout ?

For example, let's say that my (Windows) command outputs 10 on stdout, and I want to check that the output of all processes are correct :

```
let cmds = replicate 100 "echo 10"
```

How should I write the Haskell program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import System.IO
import System.Process
```

The code on the website you linked uses [`runCommand`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.23/process-1.4.3.0/System-Process.html#v:runCommand); the equivalent that gives you access to the streams is [`runInteractiveCommand`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.23/process-1.4.3.0/System-Process.html#v:runInteractiveCommand). You can then use [`hGetContents`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.23/base-4.9.1.0/System-IO.html#v:hGetContents) to read from the stream.

```
-- | Run @echo 10@ and tests whether the output is what we expect.
testOne :: IO Bool
testOne =
  runInteractiveCommand "echo 10" >>= \(_stdin, stdout, _stderr, _proc) ->
  hGetContents stdout >>= \out ->
  return (out == "10\n")
```

Then we can use [`replicateConcurrently`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.1.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:replicateConcurrently) from the `async` package to run it 100 times concurrently, and `fmap (all id)` over the result to take the boolean *and* of all the results.

```
-- | Run 'testOne' 100 times concurrently, return whether all tests succeeded.
testMany :: IO Bool
testMany =
  all id <$> replicateConcurrently 100 testOne
```